# SQL query : Need to display the list of orders made by clients ordered by the date of the first order of a client

Tags: sql

I've got a simple task to do with SQL.

I made the example below to display what I need.
The model might not be the best but it's what I have.

I need to keep all orders(rows) of a clients together while having those same blocks of rows ordered by the clients oldest order date from a specified year.

Example:

Order Table(CustomerID, OrderId, OrderDate, some other values)

Values:

```
VALUES (001, 001, 28 fev 2018, ...) -- this
VALUES (003, 002, 02 mar 2018, ...) -- this
VALUES (002, 003, 05 avr 2018, ...) -- and this
VALUES (003, 004, 17 avr 2018, ...)
VALUES (001, 005, 20 avr 2018, ...)
VALUES (001, 006, 28 avr 2018, ...)
```

Wanted result from query:

```
001, 001, 28 fev 2018, ... -- goes here
001, 005, 20 avr 2018, ...
001, 006, 28 avr 2018, ...
003, 002, 02 mar 2018, ... -- here
003, 004, 17 avr 2018, ...
002, 003, 05 avr 2018, ... -- and here
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
order by min(orderdate) over (partition by customerid),
         customerid,
         orderdate
```

I assume you are already filtering results for a single year somewhere else.  Your sample data has data only from one year.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . Look at the results.  The customers are grouped together, based on the earliest date.  The second `customerid` is to separate customers whose earliest purchase is on the same date.

Comment: Correct, I forgot about possibility of two people buying on same date.